# Nested heatmaps

Tags: r, nested, heatmap

I'm not sure if nested heatmaps is the right word, but I would like to make a heat of relative risk (RR) for a disease given you have some specific genes. However, it should be clear what the RR for the diseases is if you have 1 specific gene, 2 specific genes and so on. Something like this picture
[image]

Do you know any tools that can do something like this? Preferably in R

edit:
The data looks like this:

```
GeneA   1.05  
GeneA_B 3.08  
GeneA_C 5.6  
GeneA_B_C 8.07
```

But could be made different, if that would make the job easier.

Comment: First, can you provide some sample data that might underlie what you are looking for?  Second, is what you want a form of dendrogram?  Third, what do you mean by "RR"?

Comment: 1) The data is in this format:
GeneA 1.05
GeneA_B 3.08
GeneA_C 5.6
GeneA_B_C 8.07
2) No - will explain later
3) RR means Relative Risk
To clarify:
I want to show the relative risk of getting a disease given you have different genes.
I have already calculated the relative risk for a disease given you have GeneA, and given you have both GeneA and B or both gene A and C.
So I want to show, in a heatmap fashion, the relative risk of a diseases, given multiple combinations of genes. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Your question may have an answer in the `productplots` package.  This first attempt lacks the color and structure of yours, but it has the elements.

Create the example data frame

```
structure(list(Gene = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("GeneA", 
"GeneA_B", "GeneA_B_C", "GeneA_C"), class = "factor"), Probability = c(1.05, 3.08, 5.6, 8.07)), .Names = c("Gene", "Probability"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Create a form of tree chart

```
library("productplots")

prodplot(data = df, ~ Gene + Probability, stacked()) + theme_tufte() +
  ggtitle("Relative Risks (RR) of Various Gene Combinations")][1]
```

[image]

Comment: I can see your point. But my Idea was to be able to add an extra gene and see how that changes RR. In your examples it is treated as four independent samples. Then I might as well make a standard bar plot.

Comment: If you know the percentages each gene contributes to RR for a disease, wouldn't a stacked bar chart with each bar at 100% convey the interactions?  The stacked bar can be set to 100% for each bar.  It's hard for me to figure out what to suggest since I know nothing about genes and RR.  But I think you want to show each gene combination and the aggregate RR by combo.  Would not a segmented bar chart move in the right direction?

Comment: I guess I could make a stacked bar plot. I'm not interested in the percentage but the finale RR. I have a couple of hundred combinations of genes, thats why i thought it would be nice to make a heat map. Then i would be able to see which areas seemed to have a high RR. I guess a stacked bar plot could have a similar function, looking at which areas the bars are high. I would however still prefer if there was a way to make heat maps inside each other - or another way to make it look like my original picture.