# Visualizing nested heatmaps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, heatmap

I know the basic correlation heatmaps, but I am trying to visualize nested, or hierarchical heatmaps. I also tried [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897102/nested-heatmaps), but it wasn't quite what i am interested in. Neither did using `heatmaply`.

Like in this example:
[image: heatmap example]

[Link to the article explaining more about it](https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/MSTRWeb/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/Introduction_to_Heat_Map_Visualizations.htm)

I could not find any straightforward solution using `geom_tile()` or alike. They all refer to visualizing correlations or distances.

My data for example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-tibble(
  head = "TOTAL",
  head2 = c(rep("SUB1_A",7),rep("SUB1_B",3)), 
  head3 = c(rep("SUB2_A",4),rep("SUB2_B", 3), paste0("TITLE",1:3)),
  head4 = c(paste0("TITLE",4:10),rep(NA,3)),
  value = c(120,3702,491,1738,1730,58,231,1829,61,244)
  
) %>%  mutate(sum_head1 = sum(value,na.rm = T),.after = head) %>% 
  mutate(sum_head2 = sum(value,na.rm = T),.by = head2, .after = head2) %>% 
  mutate(sum_head3 = sum(value,na.rm = T),.by = head3, .after = head3) %>% 
  mutate(sum_head4 = sum(value,na.rm = T),.by = head4, .after = head4) %>% 
  select(-value)
df[8:10,8] <- NA
```

```
 head  sum_head1 head2  sum_head2 head3  sum_head3 head4   sum_head4
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_A      8070 SUB2_A      6051 TITLE4        120
 2 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_A      8070 SUB2_A      6051 TITLE5       3702
 3 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_A      8070 SUB2_A      6051 TITLE6        491
 4 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_A      8070 SUB2_A      6051 TITLE7       1738
 5 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_A      8070 SUB2_B      2019 TITLE8       1730
 6 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_A      8070 SUB2_B      2019 TITLE9         58
 7 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_A      8070 SUB2_B      2019 TITLE10       231
 8 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_B      2134 TITLE1      1829 NA             NA
 9 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_B      2134 TITLE2        61 NA             NA
10 TOTAL     10204 SUB1_B      2134 TITLE3       244 NA             NA
```

Here's a representation of what i would like to achieve in R:
[image: Example]
The example is for costs by categories, but can be implemented for city population size within countries >> within continents..
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you need a [treemap](https://r-graph-gallery.com/treemap.html)

Comment: Dang. That looks right about right. Thanks for referring to this! I also realized that I should pivot my data to longer format but that's the least of my concerns